# How can I use setTimeout to trigger a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set settimeout for a function, which will be start after 5 sec.

```
function test(fnn) {
   setTimeout(fnn,5000);
}
test($('#id').addClass('qwerty'));
```

Comment: A jQuery object isn't supposed to be used as a function.

Answer (score 2):

Passed parameter `fnn` is a function:

```
test(function(){ 
    $('#id').addClass('qwerty'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it.

```
setTimeout(function() { your_function(); }, 5000);
```

Comment: Why ? Just do : setTimeout(your_function, 5000);

Comment: I think `your_function` here is meant to represent `$("#id").addClass("qwerty");`. Don't know why the actual code wasn't included.